# Bash search for file in directory

Tags: bash

I have a directory with a bunch of files. As part of a script I want to look for a specific file and if that exists I want to delete it. The filename looks like this `file-4.7.0-name-1.2-client.jar` . I tried using `find /usr/lib/dir/ -name 'file-*-name-*-client.jar'`. This lists the file I am looking for however it also lists over filenames whose format is pretty close to the ones I am looking for:

```
file-4.7.0-name-1.2-client.jar
file-4.7.0-name-1.2-thin-client.jar
```

What would be the best way to get ONLY `file-4.7.0-name-1.2-client.jar`. I cant hardcode the filenames as the version numbers can vary (from `4.7.0` or `4.10.0` and `1.2` or `0.98`)

Comment: Use `locate` with `regexp` flag. See `man locate` for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a regexp with `find` and `-delete` to eliminate matching files:

```
find /usr/lib/dir/ -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./file-[0-9\.]+-name-[0-9\.]+-client.jar' -delete
```

without `delete`:

```
$ ls -1
file-4.7.0-name-1.2-client.jar
file-4.7.0-name-1.2-thin-client.jar
$ find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./file-[0-9\.]+-name-[0-9\.]+-client.jar'
./file-4.7.0-name-1.2-client.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash is quite capable of doing the pattern matching, as long as you have `extglob` turned on, which I think is the default case. RTFM about pattern matching and `shopt`. For example:

```
$ touch touch file-4.7.0-name-1.2-client.jar \
  file-4.7.0-name-1.2-thin-client.jar`enter code here`
$ echo echo file-*([0-9.])-name-*([0-9.])-client.jar
```

That matches only the first name:

```
file-4.7.0-name-1.2-client.jar
```

Be warned that if you get no match at all, this will echo your original string.